# Is there a tool to compare layers in complex PSD files?

Tags: compare, diff, photoshop, layer, psd

I seached and found one no longer available.  Perhaps there is something built in -   I'm receiving small updates in very large multi-layered documents without adequate explanation of changes, and looking for ways to speed up identifying the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check `psd-tools` library. It might help you.